# Unable to convert tiff PIL image to byte array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have a .tiff image loaded into a PIL Image and I'm trying to obtain its byte array.

This is what I'm doing:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

def image_to_byte_array(image: Image) -> bytes:
    imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(imgByteArr, format=image.format)
    imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
    return imgByteArr

im = Image.open(r"ImagePath")
im_bytes = image_to_byte_array(im)
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to save the image into **imgByteArr**.

Some .tiff images are throwing **Error setting from dictionary** and additionally I also get **_TIFFVSetField: : Ignored tag "OldSubfileType" (not supported by libtiff)**.

Is there any workaround for these cases?

Here is a [sample image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dUsn8kdNhUuGDmoYnUlKguT5TJjtqF07/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything - it only defines a function which you don't call? Where do you load your TIFF image? How do you call your function? If you have a specific image that is causing a problem, please share it - you can use Dropbox, Google Drive, GitHub  or similar. Why are you hoping to save as a TIFF when you already have a TIFF?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry for the confusion. Edited the code. Although I cannot share the document. I'm not hoping to save the tiff, I need to work with its byte array. It's a tiff document generated from scanning an image and saved in my file system. It happens with all images scanned from this scanner

Comment: What's wrong with `im_bytes = open(r"ImagePath",'rb').read()` ?

Comment: If your scanner always produces *"unhappy"* images, surely you can scan some nondescript squiggle you have drawn on a piece of paper and share that - it shouldn't be confidential, surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I uploaded a sample image. Your suggestion works, but I don't have control over that part of code. I just get the PIL Image and I have to get the bytearray from it

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know if it works and if it causes any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in a rush at the moment, but there is something in the image (I'm guessing a tag or compression or some attribute) that prevents you from writing the image.

You can see the error generated more simply like this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(...path...)
im.save('anything.tif')
```

One way to get rid of all the extended attributes and metadata is to convert the image to a Numpy array and from there back to a PIL Image. This *"round-trip"* through Numpy can't propagate any attributes, just pixels, so it then works:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(...path...)

# Round-trip through Numpy array to strip attributes and metadata
im = Image.fromarray(np.array(im))

im.save('anything.tif')    # works
```

I'll investigate further when I have time, but this may work as an interim method.

Comment: Nice trick! Works as expected. Thank you